# Turn off highlighting on UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm trying to use a UIBarButtonItem to put a title on my UIToolbar.  I'm using the plain style and that looks fine, but I can't seem to get it to stop highlighting on touch.  The Shows Touch When Highlighted option isn't available for the bar button items.  Is there a quick and easy way to do this?  I'm trying to do the building in interface builder so I can see what I'm doing.  I'd prefer not to build the toolbar in the view did load every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property responsible for this is accessible in the `UIButton` class:

```
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

You can access this (programmatically) in a UIBarButtonItem by assigning a UIButton to the bar button item's `customView` property, and configuring the button. You can do this in Interface Builder too: drag a UIButton onto a UIToolbar, and it will automatically embed it in a UIBarButtonItem for you - then look for the "Shows Touch On Highlight" checkbox under the button's settings.

Incidentally, I don't know how you're customising your buttons so feel free to ignore this, but if your button looks and behaves like a standard toolbar item then users will expect the glow effect.

Comment: This button itself is just a title.  I just need a toolbar so I can have a bunch of buttons, and didn't know any other way to put a title in the middle of it.

Comment: @btate: Ah yes, the title. When I needed a title, I actually just used a standard UILabel with appropriate formatting. Perhaps not as elegant as embedding one in the toolbar as you are doing, but maybe a little simpler. In case you're interested, the formatting for such a label is Helvetica Bold 20.0, white text color, 50% opacity black shadow with -1 vertical offset.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a solution that could be used without any modification to my XIB structure.
The most obvious and simple one worked: subclass `UIBarButtonItem`:

UITitleBarButtonItem.h:

```
//
//  UITitleBarButtonItem.m
//  Created by Guillaume Cerquant - MacMation on 09/08/12.
//

/*
 * A UIBarButtonItem that does not show any highlight on the touch
 * Drag and drop a normal UIBarButtonItem in your xib and set its subclass to UITitleBarButtonItem
 */
@interface UITitleBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem
@end
```

UITitleBarButtonItem.m:

```
#import "UITitleBarButtonItem.h"

@implementation UITitleBarButtonItem

// Only caring about UITitleBarButtonItem set up in Interface Builder. Update this class if you need to instantiate it from code

- (void) awakeFromNib {
    UIView *theView = [self valueForKey:@"view"];

    if ([theView respondsToSelector:@selector(setUserInteractionEnabled:)]) {
        theView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}

@end
```

Tested on iOS 5 and the one we aren't allowed to talk yet.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative: Use a UIBarButtonItem in the plain style and additionally cover the toolbar in the appropriate area with a UIView that has a clear background. The view consumes the taps and hides them from the bar button item. Make sure you set the autoresizing mask correctly.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to set it to disabled, and adjust the `titleAttributes` for each `UIControlState`

```
let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
    .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16),
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.white
]

barButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .enabled)
barButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .disabled)
barButton.isEnabled = false
```