# How do I remove UIBarButtonItem glow programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem

Unfortunately there is no showsTouchWhenHighlighted for UIBarButtonItem and I can't edit my button from the toolbar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property responsible for this is accessible in the UIButton class:

```
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

You can access this (programmatically) in a UIBarButtonItem by assigning a UIButton to the bar button item's customView property, and configuring the button. You can do this in Interface Builder too: drag a UIButton onto a UIToolbar, and it will automatically embed it in a UIBarButtonItem for you - then look for the "Shows Touch On Highlight" checkbox under the button's settings.

Incidentally, I don't know how you're customising your buttons so feel free to ignore this, but if your button looks and behaves like a standard toolbar item then users will expect the glow effect.

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916342/turn-off-highlighting-on-uibarbuttonitem)

**EDIT**:

Try this then:

```
UIImage* buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"header.navigation.back.png"];     
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
aButton.frame =  CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width/2, 32);
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backToPriorView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
```

Comment: I specifically mentioned I cannot use the interface builder so it's irrelevant. So how can I use showsTouchWhenHighlighted after all?

Comment: Actually you need not add a UIImage. You can set the background of aButton to whatever you like.

Comment: I believe that code block is missing this call: `aButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted  = NO` (in Swift I'm using `aButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false`)