# iOS navigation items animates differently when clicked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I need to change the text and action of the navigation item, currently, I am doing it by providing the bar button items. But my problem is when I click it, it shows click only on the item I clicked not all the items I have added to `leftBarButtonItems`.

I tried using a custom view(`UIBarButtonItem(customView: UIButton())`). But It becomes smaller and I was not able to resize it. Please see the below image to understand the problem I am having. This is the situation after clicking on the back button. Thanks for your time.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916342/turn-off-highlighting-on-uibarbuttonitem .
maybe it will help you

Answer (score 0):

please use custom navigation bar
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zS-CCd4xmRY
I hope this is helpful for you

Comment: My navigation bar is already customized that way. I have two UIBarButtonItem in ```leftBarButtonItems```  array. one with an image and another with the title. 
Because they are different items they are showing click events differently, I tried with a single button and set its image but it becomes smaller in size than the regular back button of navigation.